# Combining Column Values in an Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

In order to simplify a stacked bar chart, I am looking to sum up the counts of multiple columns I have in my pivot table.  For example, in this sample table, I would like to combine Fruits and Vegetables into one column, so that each bar will comprised of three colors: one for Meats, one for Grains, and one for Fruits+Vegetables.

[Pivot Table and Stacked Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MUx6.png)

For reference, this is the data source:

[Data Source table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lniPO.png)

I tried adding a Calculated Field, but I'm not sure if I can use specific values from a column in the Formulas field.  Is there a way to create something like this from a pivot table, or should I be taking a different approach to this all together?

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Excel 2016, -- pretty sure it's the same with older versions, but the premise is the same.

In your pivot table, Select the Pivot Table Tools> Analyze tab, then "Fields, Items",then pull down to"Calculated fields". Enter a name for the generated field, and the formula you want to use:

[image]

In my example, I added the fields `Fruit` and `Vegi's` from my available pivot table fields (which is based on my data table).

Then select the calculated field as you would any other..

[image]

and create the chart as usual.

Hope this helps.